# Separate search in different tables with sphinx

Tags: sphinx

In my case content are saving in table
content_en

Search with sphinx works good.

I would to add another table content_es and make search in this table.

And if user will be search on en version site - i would use content_en table, if on spain version - content_es table.

I can search in 2 tables and on PHP side make filter, but I think it's not correct.

How it's make correct ? (like $sphinx->SetOption() or $sphinx->SetIndex()) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$res = $cl->Query($query,"content_es");
```